# How do I ignore changes by a certain user in Jenkins/HG?

Tags: mercurial, hudson, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with a HG repository. There is a post-build script that updates some files and pushes them to the repository. Since Jenkins is set up to build on repo changes, the update triggers a rebuild in an infinite loop.

Changing the directory structure to avoid this seems difficult, so I figured the best option would be to simply ignore changes made by the user "jenkins".

Is there a way to let Jenkins ignore changes by a certain user?

Comment: Hm. Source for the Mercurial plugin doesn't seem to show anything promising in that regard: https://github.com/jenkinsci/mercurial-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialSCM.java

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess you don't want to push anything from you CI-server into the central repo, you can set up the default-push path of the clone that it points to itself. So any push without an explicit given URL will target the clone and not the central repository.

```
$ cat << EOF >> .hg/hgrc
[paths]
default-push = $PWD
EOF

$ hg ci -m'test'

$ hg push
pushing to /home/foo/bar
searching for changes
no changes found

$ hg push ../source
pushing to ../source
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 3 changes to 1 files

$ hg pull
pulling from /home/foo/source
searching for changes
no changes found
```

See http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html#id349161 for more details.

Comment: Actually, I want to push to the central repo :\